# How to disprove $X ∩ Y ≠ ∅$ and $X ∩ Z ≠ ∅$ then $Y ∩ Z ≠ ∅$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

For all sets $X,Y,Z$. If $X ∩ Y ≠ ∅$ and $X ∩ Z ≠ ∅$ then $Y ∩ Z ≠ ∅$.

Would I take the contrapositive of the implication and disprove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X=\{1,2,3\}$, $Y=\{1\}$ and $Z=\{3\}$ disproves the statement

Comment: can I disprove it just with a direct example?

Comment: @Jeff yes.  It is disproof by counterexample and is a common technique to disprove things.

Comment: Yes, you can. For every sentence of the form "All..." you can proof that it is false if you find a counterexample

Comment: @JeffBridges This **is** a direct example disproving the statement.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false, take $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{1\}$ and $Z=\{2\}$. Then $Y \cap Z = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$A=\{1,3,5,7,9\},$$ $$B=\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8\},$$ $$ C=\{1\}$$ $$A \cap B = \{3,5,7\} \neq \varnothing,$$ $$A \cap C =\{1\} \neq \varnothing,$$ but $$B \cap C = \varnothing.$$